# How do I stop getting job alerts for a specific industry?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I’m looking for jobs near New York City, where it feels like 80% of the job alerts are for jobs in finance.  I don’t want to work in finance.

I tried selecting every industry *except* finance in Job Preferences, but I got an error saying I can only select up to 4.

Can that limit be raised?  Otherwise, can we have a way to blacklist industries like we can blacklist technologies?

Comment: I got as far as listing `automotive`(industry) and `Windows`(technology) as no-nos in my CV. Your question is godsent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now select industries to exclude in [your job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

[image]

Jobs with excluded industries will be excluded from your job alerts.